# Using the right format but getting error on mysql, importing tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to import bunch of tables but i keep getting this message:

check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GO  SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dept](' at line 2

[image]

```
    USE cmpt354
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dept](
    [did] [int] NOT NULL,
    [dname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [budget] [float] NULL,
    [managerid] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Dept] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [did] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Emp]    Script Date: 22/02/2013 12:14:10 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emp](
    [eid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ename] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [age] [int] NULL,
    [salary] [real] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Emp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [eid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Works]    Script Date: 22/02/2013 12:14:10 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Works](
    [eid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [did] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pct_time] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Dept] ([did], [dname], [budget], [managerid]) VALUES (1, N'Hardware', 1048572.12, 141582651)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Dept] ([did], [dname], [budget], [managerid]) VALUES (2, N'Operations', 4099101, 287321212)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Dept] ([did], [dname], [budget], [managerid]) VALUES (3, N'Legal', 222988.13, 248965255)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Dept] ([did], [dname], [budget], [managerid]) VALUES (4, N'Marketing', 538099.54, 548977562)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Dept] ([did], [dname], [budget], [managerid]) VALUES (5, N'Software', 400011.12, 141582651)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Dept] ([did], [dname], [budget], [managerid]) VALUES (6, N'Production', 12099101, 578875478)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Dept] ([did], [dname], [budget], [managerid]) VALUES (7, N'Shipping', 5, 489456522)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (11564812, N'John Williams', 35, 74098)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (15487874, N'Gene Edwards', 51, 41008)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (15645489, N'Daniel Evans', 25, 40312)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (51135593, N'Maria White', 22, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (54879887, N'Dorthy Lewis', 33, 41008)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (60839453, N'Charles Harris', 24, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (74454898, N'Scott Bell', 23, 70100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (90873519, N'Elizabeth Taylor', 27, 33055)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (98784544, N'Eric Collins', 23, 41008)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (112348546, N'Joseph Thompson', 26, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (115987938, N'Christopher Garcia', 60, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (128778823, N'William Ward', 33, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (132977562, N'Angela Martinez', 31, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (141582651, N'Mary Johnson', 44, 94011)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (141582657, N'Stanley Browne', 23, 14093)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (142519864, N'Susan Martin', 39, 56990)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (156465461, N'Eric Cooper', 26, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (156489494, N'Gil Richardson', 32, 70100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (159542516, N'Matt Nelson', 33, 48990)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (178949844, N'Chad Stewart', 29, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (179887498, N'Dorthy Howard', 28, 40312)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (242518965, N'James Smith', 68, 27099)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (248965255, N'Barbara Wilson', 48, 95021)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (254099823, N'Patricia Jones', 28, 42783)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (254898318, N'Gim Rogers', 25, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (267894232, N'Paul Hall', 25, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (269734834, N'Rick Carter', 38, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (274878974, N'Harry Watson', 30, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (280158572, N'Margaret Clark', 40, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (287321212, N'Michael Miller', 62, 131072)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (289562686, N'Thomas Robinson', 34, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (291795563, N'Haywood Kelly', 36, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (298489484, N'Lisa Gray', 31, 24998)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (301221823, N'Juan Rodriguez', 30, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (310454876, N'Milo Brooks', 22, 39910)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (318548912, N'Ann Mitchell', 23, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (320874981, N'Daniel Lee', 23, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (322654189, N'Lisa Walker', 38, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (334568786, N'William Moore', 32, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (348121549, N'Trey Phillips', 69, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (351565322, N'Nancy Allen', 30, 39910)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (355548984, N'Tom Murphy', 41, 32175)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (356187925, N'Robert Brown', 28, 35431)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (390487451, N'Mark Coleman', 42, 39910)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (451519864, N'Mark Young', 34, 39910)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (454565232, N'Louis Jenkins', 20, 39910)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (455798411, N'Luis Hernandez', 44, 39910)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (486512566, N'David Anderson', 20, 25199)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (489221823, N'Richard Jackson', 33, 32996)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (489456522, N'Linda Davis', 26, 25971)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (548977562, N'Donald King', 43, 92048)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (550156548, N'George Wright', 42, 41008)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (552455318, N'Ana Lopez', 35, 41008)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (556784565, N'Kenneth Hill', 81, 41008)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (567354612, N'Karen Scott', 70, 39910)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (573284895, N'Steven Green', 29, 39910)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (574489456, N'Betty Adams', 39, 39910)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (578875478, N'Edward Baker', 50, 101071)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Emp] ([eid], [ename], [age], [salary]) VALUES (619023588, N'Jennifer Thomas', 24, 34654)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (142519864, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (242518965, 1, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (141582651, 1, 50)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (141582651, 5, 50)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (141582657, 1, 25)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (141582657, 5, 75)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (11564812, 3, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (254099823, 3, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (356187925, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (489456522, 7, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (287321212, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (248965255, 3, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (159542516, 4, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (90873519, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (486512566, 4, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (619023588, 1, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (489221823, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (548977562, 4, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (578875478, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (51135593, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (60839453, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (112348546, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (115987938, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (132977562, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (269734834, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (280158572, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (301221823, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (318548912, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (320874981, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (322654189, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (348121549, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (351565322, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (451519864, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (455798411, 2, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (550156548, 2, 50)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (552455318, 2, 25)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (556784565, 2, 25)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (567354612, 2, 75)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (573284895, 2, 50)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (574489456, 2, 50)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (15645489, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (15487874, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (54879887, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (98784544, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (74454898, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (156489494, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (179887498, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (156465461, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (128778823, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (178949844, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (298489484, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (274878974, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (267894232, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (254898318, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (289562686, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (291795563, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (334568786, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (355548984, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (310454876, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (390487451, 6, 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Works] ([eid], [did], [pct_time]) VALUES (454565232, 6, 50)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Works]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Works_Dept] FOREIGN KEY([did])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Dept] ([did])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Works] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Works_Dept]
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [company] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
```

Comment: if you run SQL server queries on mysql. what you get is errors

Comment: This is not oracle

Comment: Why do you expect that T-SQL statements mixed with SSMS specific delimiters will work on MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

That is an SQL Server script you're trying to run on MySQL. It's a different language, it's just not going to work.

You will have to rewrite that script to something MySQL understands. For example, the `create table` statement should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Dept` (
  `did` int NOT NULL,
  `dname` varchar(255) NULL,
  `budget` float NULL,
  `managerid` int NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`did`)
);
```

The respective insert statements will have to be like this:

```
INSERT `Dept` (`did`, `dname`, `budget`, `managerid`) VALUES (1, 'Hardware', 1048572.12, 141582651);
```